# C++ move bytewise through memory

Tags: c++, memory

I have a shared memory with this structure (see codesnippet 1), all values are hex values:

```
Position 00:  55; // memory overall, byte 00 to 03;
Position 01:  00;
Position 02:  00;
Position 03:  00;
Position 04:  47; // memory for header information, byte 04 to 07;
Position 05:  00
Position 06:  00;
Position 07:  00;
Position 08:  00; // version, byte 08, 09;
Position 09:  00;
Position 0A:  64; // rate of refreshing memory between processes
Position 0B:  00;
Position 0C:  00;
Position 0D:  00;
Position 0E:  00;
Position 0F:  4L;
...
```

As you can see in the comments I know which byte represents what information. Anyway I cast the memory in a struct (see codesnippet 2). The properties in this struct are currently integer-values. The values 55 and 47 are stored in the first two properties. As it seems, '00' will be neglected and I am not able to read the whole memory byte by byte. How can I read the memory bytewise?

codesnippet 2:

```
struct Shm {
    int memorySize; // size of memory space; min 4 bytes, Position 00 - 03; ie 55 is a hex value and means 84 
    int headerSize; // size of header space; min 4 bytes, Position 04 - 07; ie 47 (hex), so 71 (dec) same number as config-dialog
    int byte3; // version number 
    int byte4; // refreshing interval in msec
    ...
```

Moroever there are some areas in the memory, which contain some chars - how to cast those byte-values to chars and create words of them, currently I am only able to cast to int-values (see codesnippet 3)

```
int main(void){
    std::cout << "*** Start SharedMemory  ***\n";
    HANDLE hMapFile;
    ...
    Shm * pBuf = (Shm *) MapViewOfFile(hMapFile, FILE_MAP_ALL_ACCESS, 0, 0, BUF_SIZE); 
    std::cout << " Debug  memorySize " << ": " << dec << pBuf->memorySize << " (dec); " << hex << pBuf->memorySize << " (hex); " << &pBuf->memorySize << " (Adresse);\n";   // 84 Bytes
    std::cout << " Debug  headerSize " << ": " << dec << pBuf->headerSize << " (dec);       << hex << pBuf->headerSize << " (hex);\n";  // 71 Bytes
    std::cout << " Debug  byte3 " << ": " << dec << pBuf->byte3 << " (dec); " << hex << pBuf->byte3 << " (hex);\n";
    ...
```

Comment: Based on what you've shown it would seem your version is a short, not an int.

Comment: Thanks for your comment RetiredNinja, how do know that version is a short not an int? I guess because it is stored in two bytes instead of four?

Comment: Yes, if you want your struct to align with the data you've shown then you need to size the variables appropriately.  If there's only 16 bits there you need a 16 bit variable.  Of course, once you do that you'll need to pack the struct to force the next int to align right after the short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remark: casting files to struct is a bad idea. alignment, size of int, endian  can differ in different systems.

Casting to any part of file:

```
const char  * pBuf = (const char *) MapViewOfFile...
const Mytype * myVar = (const Mytype *)(pBuf + myVarOffset);
```

So for strings just add offset to pBuf (pBuf + myVarOffset - is all you need) - and you get start pointer to string. (Hope there is a zero byte at the end of the string in the file.)

if your struct is supposed to have one buffer/string variable with unspecified length the following code may help:

```
struct MyStruct
{
   int size_of_string;
   char my_string[1]; //can be used as a long string of size size_of_string
};
```

note that sizeof(MyStruct) will not give you the right value in this case so you can not allocate this object with 'new' and on stack (use malloc/free instead).

I'd recommend you to read about serialization.

Answer (score 3):

You may have aliasing and alignment problems. Read this for more details: [strict aliasing and alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9964418/1175253)

Basically, one can copy the memory into a local structure to avoid such problems:

```
Shm shmInfo;

memcpy(&shmInfo,&pBuf[shmInfoOffset],sizeof(shmInfo));
```

Comment: Thanks Sam, I tried your idea and I am wondering what value shmInfoOffset must be, if I want to get the value of byte at index 3?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I wanted to give a general example. `shmInfoOffset` is just the offset of the `Shm` instance in that shared memory block. It looks like your structure is at offset `0` anyway, so you could just pass `pBuf`. `memcpy` would initialize a local copy of that shared structure. You wouldn't need to fetch single bytes, because you could add `unsigned char` fields to the structure, perhaps with an `union`, which would allow accessing single bytes in a four byte integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you deal with binary data, it's a good idea to write such functions:

```
char getByte(char* data,int offset);
void setByte(char* data,int offset,char value);
char getWord(char* data,int offset);
...
void setLongword(char* ptr,int value);
```

Then you can create functions which makes your code pretty and readable:

```
int getVersion(char* data) {
  return (int)getByte(data,8); 
}
```

Using macros for that purpose is also not a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

If your chars are packed 4 bytes into one int, then the below example might help.  Note that endianess must be a consideration.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void appendCharsFromInt(std::string& inString, int intAsChars, int charCount)
{
    char someChars[4];
    memcpy(someChars, &intAsChars, sizeof(int));
    inString.append(someChars, charCount);
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int byte0 = 0x6c6c6548;
    int byte1 = 0x6f57206f;
    int byte2 = 0x00646c72;

    std::string completeString;

    appendCharsFromInt(completeString, byte0, 4);
    appendCharsFromInt(completeString, byte1, 4);
    appendCharsFromInt(completeString, byte2, 4);

    std::cout << completeString << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Chris O, how do you know, what the value of byte0 to byte2 are?

Comment: I just picked the hardcoded values for demo purposes, but those would really come from your `Shm` struct.