# UB with structure casting of different types?

Tags: c++, struct, network-programming, undefined-behavior

Does the following piece of code contains an Undefined Behavior? The code only tries to fill `sockaddr_storage` structure with `sockaddr_in` structure format and then read it back via same type ie. `sockaddr_in`. Also in the following calls, that `sockaddr_storage` structure is passed with a cast to `sockaddr` structure. I saw similar question and wondering if this code contains it too. This program works fine wherever I've tested it -

[Run Online](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/myjnFX0YNjHEqLE4)

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void fillAF_INET(sockaddr_storage &s){
  sockaddr_in *p = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in *>(&s);
  p->sin_family = AF_INET;
  p->sin_port = htons(10000);
  inet_pton(AF_INET, "127.0.0.1", &p->sin_addr);
}

// void fillAF_INET6(sockaddr_storage &s){...}
// void fillAF_UNIX(sockaddr_storage &s){...}

int main(){
  sockaddr_storage s;
  fillAF_INET(s);

  sockaddr_in *p = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in *>(&s);
  std::cout << ntohs(p->sin_port) << " ";
  std::cout << boolalpha << (p->sin_family == AF_INET);

  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0);
  int r = bind(sock, (sockaddr *)&s, sizeof(s));
  // further calls

  return 0;
}
```

The result comes : `10000 true` which is absolutely correct!

Comment: removed error handling for keeping it small..

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964418/strict-aliasing-and-alignment

Answer (score 3):

Code is correct. Here is what the Open Group says about `sockaddr_storage`:

> The `<sys/socket.h>` header shall define the `sockaddr_storage` structure.
>   This structure shall be:
>
> - Large enough to accommodate all supported protocol-specific address
>     structures
> - Aligned at an appropriate boundary so that pointers to it can be cast
>     as pointers to protocol-specific address structures and used to access
>     the fields of those structures without alignment problems

Comment: 'It is correct' - do you mean it is UB or the code is correct and it is not UB? See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42178179/will-casting-around-sockaddr-storage-and-sockaddr-in-break-strict-aliasing

Comment: This is wrong, see also - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42176962/fill-sockaddr-storage-struct-with-values-of-sockaddr-in