# What is the idiomatic cpp14 way to read an int32_t from a char* buffer?

Tags: c++, c++14, endianness

Given a char buffer c containing an int (little endian).
How to read it as int32_t?

I wrote this code but it doesn't feel idiomatic cpp.

```
int32_t v;
char* p = (char*)&v;
for (int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
    *(p+i) = *(c+i);
}
```

Comment: @ DavidHaim it make sense I tried this 
int32_t v = static_cast< int32_t >(*c); 
but it does not work

Comment: @DavidHaim Eg. that casting fails on big endians? Or that, depending on the usage, you get UB (strict aliasing)?

Comment: What is wrong with using bit-shifting and | operators?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky Optimizer do not like this solution but they produce optimal code with the code above or with memcpy: https://godbolt.org/g/iMy1mn

Comment: @Oliv std::int32_t v = *reinterpret_cast<std::int32_t*>(p); =>
 movsx eax, byte ptr [rdi] VS std::memcpy(&k,buffer,4); => mov eax, dword ptr [rdi] I don't quite get it there.

Comment: @Pierrot Your code is fine (as long as the int on the buffer is little endian too).  What showes the link i provided is that what is proposed by Artemy Vysotsky produces suboptimal binary code (if I did not get wrong). Nevertheless, after having think about it twice, the solution proposed by Artemy Vysotsky is the most robust and the only one that never results neither implementation defined nor undefined behavior.

Comment: @Pierrot There is a debate below, and every think is agree. Actualy each of the answer that were given to you could be fine, depending on the way your buffer is initialized. is it: 1-an array of char on which an int has been built or the results of the cast to a char* of a pointer to int; 2 - or a buffer of char on which the representation of an int has been stored; 3- data coming from some I/O?

Comment: @Oliv I did not thought a simple question like that would raise such debate

Comment: @Pierrot I have asked some similar question, and the conclusion was, the c++ object model is underspecified... In your case, I think the troubles is caused by different interpretation of a sentence in your question "a buffer of char containing an int". Even if our mental model of a simple CPU does not make difference about between 2 "buffers of char", compiler does. The C++ virtual machine deal with object, lifetime, and type, if you violate that, bad surprises happen.

Comment: The concequence is oftenly that code compiled by the "unworried" to cite Stroustrup, must be compiled with -fno-strict-aliasing, which realy make the code slower. That could happen, in the near future,if you use the answer proposing reinterpret_cast. But for short lived project that will be thrown to the trash they belong to, this kind of code is ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to solve your issue in a portable and safe manner, use `memcpy` as [n.m.'s answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46620160/598696). Otherwise, here's a more dangerous technique:

**Note that this is UB.** Only use the technique below if you are **completely** sure that the buffer contains the right amount of data and that the buffer and data are **properly aligned**.

If you are sure that the endianness of the system matches the one of the data stored in the `char*` buffer, you can use [`reinterpret_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast):

```
std::int32_t v = *reinterpret_cast<std::int32_t*>(p);
```

There's no Standard-compliant way of doing the above transformation. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46644316/c-strict-aliasing-agnostic-cast#46644542) for more details.

Comment: Reinterpret cast doesn't work with improperly aligned data. The behaviour is undefined.

Comment: @n.m. it's only undefined if the data or the buffer are not properly aligned, right? I.e. if the OP's example buffer and target `int32` are properly aligned, this will be fine.

Comment: My understanding is that strict aliasing is not just about alignment, it is about allowing the processor to take short cuts. So it would be undefined behavior regardless to alias memory with anything other than `char*`, `unsigned char*` and (now) `std::byte*`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9964418/strict-aliasing-and-alignment

Comment: This is undefined behavior. The answer of n.m. is the rigt one.

Comment: While the whole "undefined in general, even when properly aligned" bla bla vs. `memcpy` is rather academical, I think this answer (while qualifying it at the end), DOES have a real practical problem: when casting from a character buffer, chances are really high that the data is IN FACT not correctly aligned and this does cause problems in actual practice. So yes, I really think this answer is kinda wrong, in that having the correct alignment out of a char buffer is ... unlikely. (Although it "just works" on e.g. a x86 platform last time I checked, its really not something we should reccommend)

Answer (score 7):

The only portable way to copy *binary* data from a `char*` buffer to any other data type is with `memcpy` (or an equivalent byte-copying merhod such as `std::copy` or one of your own that mimics this behaviour).

```
 memcpy(&my_number, my_buffer, sizeof(my_number));
```

Of course the buffer should contain correct bits for a given data type. If it originated from memory copying *from* the same data tyoe on the same machine, then endianness doesn't come into play. Otherwise  you have to rearrange the bytes in the required order (either in place or in a temporary buffer), or swap the bytes in a platform-dependent manner in the in the integer itself (maybe with htonl and friends).

Comment: I wouldn't say that this is the only way, unions seem to fine here too.

Comment: There is nothing preventing you from writing your own loop or using standard algorithms like `std::copy` too. As long as you are using `char*`, `unsigned char*`, `std::byte*` which legally alias any other types.

Comment: @Galik if you can do this correctly you don't need to ask this question.

Answer (score 6):

There is no magic idiomatic way to handle endianness — endianness is an I/O issue. Either use the `htonl()` and `ntohl()` functions (available on *every* system) or just decode them yourself (as you are doing). I recommend writing functions to do it (make your life easier, and verifiable).

Comment: It should be noted that those functions convert to and from *big endian* (network byte order) whereas the question is asking about converting from *little endian*.

Comment: Thanks @Dúthomhas you answer helps as well

Answer (score 3):

There is no standard function to discover the endianness of your system. However given such a function `bool is_little_endian()` that returns true only on little endian systems you might do something like this:

```
std::uint32_t read_from_little_endian(char* buf)
{
    std::uint32_t u;

    if(is_little_endian())
        std::copy(buf, buf + sizeof(u), (char*)&u);
    else
        std::reverse_copy(buf, buf + sizeof(u), (char*)&u);

    return u;
}
```

The important point is always to cast your `std::uint32_t*` to a `char*` because only `char*` can legally *alias* all other types.

Comment: Actually, there is a fairly standard way to _discover_ endianness — you can even have the preprocessor do it for you: use a byte string/array and compare to an int. (Now if only <endian.h> were standardized...)

Comment: @Dúthomhas Fails with different charsets/encodings

Comment: @deviantfan Er, name a charset/encoding that is different for codes 0 and 1.

Comment: @Dúthomhas See Ebcdic

Comment: You’re telling me that `"\0\0\0\1"` is _different_ when using EBCDIC?